# Align equation in centre

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

[image]

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
J_{hop}=\mathit{\frac{\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{2} }\sqrt{\frac{{\in }_{fg}}{{\in }_{mq}}}}\mathit{\frac{R}{{d^}_{S}} } 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With the code above, that is what I get.

I would like to have a centred equation like this. How could I go about this?
Svjour is a springer class.

[image]

Comment: Well, first, your desired behaviour is the default behaviour for `equation`. Your MWE is not complete at all, please show us what else is in your preamble, you haven't even specified a `\documentclass`. Second, you seem to be using `\in` - do you mean `epsilon` (or perhaps, I suspect more likely, `\varepsilon`). Please note these are absolutely different symbols for different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svjour3.cls` file has

```
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue\ExecuteOptions{fleqn}}
```

which means that, whenever the `twocolumn` option is selected, displayed equations will be flush with the left margin (it also has `\mathindent=0pt` to that effect).

So if your aim is to submit a paper, you should not try and change this behavior.

However, there are other things to note about your code. First, `txfonts` is not recommended and it would be better to do

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

but, as said before, the choice of fonts is the copy editors' business, not yours. So remove the line altogether.

Your formula can be improved. You have too many braces and wrong `\mathit` commands.

```
First
\begin{equation}
J_{hop}=
  \frac{\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{2}}
  \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon_{fg}}{\varepsilon_{mq}}}
  \frac{R}{d^4s}
\end{equation}
Second
\begin{equation}
J_{\mathrm{hop}}=
  \frac{\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{2}}
  \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon_{\mathrm{fg}}}{\varepsilon_{\mathrm{mq}}}}
  \frac{R}{d^4s}
\end{equation}
```

Depending on the meaning of the subscripts, you should use `\mathrm` around them when they denote *textual* objects, such as abbreviations, and nothing when they denote math variables.

Note that `\in` denotes set membership, the Greek letter is either `\epsilon` or `\varepsilon` (with slightly different shapes).

I rendered the final denominator as `d^4s`, because `{d^4}_S` seems quite wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile as is.  The following code compiles and centers the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    J_{hop}=\mathit{\frac{\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{2} }\sqrt{\frac{{\in }_{fg}}{{\in }_{mq}}}}\mathit{\frac{R}{{d}_{S}} } 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @JPi, I have edited the question. I just included the document class svjour. Could I get the same result with this class.

Comment: @Abdulhameed Well, if you're using a class file provided by a journal because you wish to submit to that journal and they've provided you with a file to use, then presumably they've set up their class file to provide the formatting they require and you have to go along with that. As I say, `equation`'s default behaviour is centred, if equations aren't centred in this class, that's a deliberate design decision, and presumably it's not up to you.

Comment: *If* however, you've just borrowed this template because you like the look of it, that's another thing. But using non-standard templates you don't understand has been the undoing of many TeX users. There be dragons.

Comment: Thanks @Au101. I intend to send  an article to the journal